# Aggregating with multiple columns and getting the average value in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

`df`

```
month      merchant   sales
11           M1        10   
11           M1        6     
11           M2        7
12           M3        8
12           M4        9
12           M2        6
10           M5        11
```

I want to group by `month, merchant` and get average (rounded by 2 decimal) `sales` for each merchant on each month.

For example, as shown below, for `month 11`, for `M1` it can be calculated as `((10+6)/(10+6+7))` for `M2` calculated as `(7/(10+6+7))`. and their average summation for particular month shouldn't greater than 1. For example for `month 11` their summation is `0.69+0.30 ~ 1`.

The output that I am looking for is:

```
month      merchant   sales    average
11           M1        16        0.69  
11           M2        7         0.30 
12           M3        8         0.30
12           M4        9         0.39
12           M2        6         0.26
10           M5        11        1
```

I have tried this but couldn't get what I want.

```
df =df.groupby('month')[['merchant', 'sales']].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Can anyone help on this in python pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by month and sum up the sales, then divide sales by sum:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['month', 'merchant'])['sales'].sum().reset_index()

df2['average'] = df2['sales'] / df2.groupby(['month'])['sales'].transform(sum)

df2
   month merchant  sales   average
0     10       M5     11  1.000000
1     11       M1     16  0.695652
2     11       M2      7  0.304348
3     12       M2      6  0.260870
4     12       M3      8  0.347826
5     12       M4      9  0.391304
```

Comment: @mck For the example that I have gave, it works perfect. But I have tried your code, on large data set that I have, it doesn't  give that I want. Now, I have updated the question. Could it be possible updating your solution according to my updated question?